# Hand sieve vs nut milk bag for straining plant milk

Tags: dairy-substitutes

I have been making non-dairy milk (mostly oat milk) for a while using a nut milk bag to strain, which has recently torn. I am looking for a replacement, and was wondering whether there is much difference in the end results between using a) a nut milk bag like [this](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Lovetree-Products-Professional-Cheesecloth-Replacement/dp/B00KY3DZNM/ref=sr_1_6?crid=NZ1REA7P4J9Q&dchild=1&keywords=nut%20milk%20bag&qid=1589106672&sprefix=nut%20mil%2Caps%2C191&sr=8-6) and b) a hand sieve like [this](https://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B0001IWZY0?tag=duckduckgo-ffcm-uk-21&linkCode=osi&th=1).

I think the sieve will be easier to use than the bag, but are the results likely to be different/worse than using a nut milk bag?

When I say worse, I am essentially looking to avoid an overly thick or gloopy milk.

Comment: My typo was corrected to "overly thin", but should read "overly thick". Good catch on the typo though :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A hand sieve will likely not be fine enough to catch the smaller bits of blended oats that can 'cloud' your milk and give it a gritty texture. A nut milk bag really is best, but if you're looking for a quick alternative then a pair of tights can do the trick in the short-term!

Comment: Agreed. Tights/Panties work great for oat milk.

Comment: So I ended up trying both methods. I found that by using a fine-mesh seive, I was able to make oat milk that was suitable for all uses except tea/coffee - there is a very fine oat residue that, when given a good shake, gives a thicker, almost Oatly-like consistency, but isn't suitable for hot drinks. It is however great on cereal - better than the nut-bag results to be honest, as it was creamier! 
The nut bag gave the best results for hot drinks, but I found it so much less convenient than using a seive, I am sticking with a seive and using barista milks for hot drinks. Sorted!!

Answer (score 1):

You could consider cheese cloth or muslin as another alternative. It is designed to let liquid trough but still has enough tensile strength to not break when you try and remove the solids from it.

It may not be a alternative at all, because it could be that a 'nut-bag' is just cheesecloth by another name.